When entering Chinese in the `Textfield` within the` popup`, the input method candidate box is always positioned at the top-left corner
I'm a JavaFX beginner and I'm not sure how JavaFX handles input method positioning.
This issue can be reproduced on both Windows 11 and Windows 10, as well as with JavaFX 17 and JavaFX 22.
Sample code
public class InputTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
        stage.show();
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.getContent().add(new TextField());
        popup.show(stage);
    }

}


The screenshot below shows the TextField directly within the Stage, and the candidate box is positioned correctly.

In Chrome, the input method candidate box always follows the input cursor.


Perhaps this is a bug with JavaFX. Consider submitting a bug report and/or opening a discussion in an appropriate mailing list. Though I'm a little confused why you are using a Popup in your example. Is it necessary to reproduce the problem?

@Slaw Yes, if the TextField is in a Stage, the candidate box follows correctly.

Pardon me, but your question is not clear. A Popup is a window with no title bar nor borders and no background. You add a TextField to a Popup. By default, the Popup is displayed in the center of its owner - which is the Stage in your sample code. Hence, when you run your application, the TextField appears in the center of the Stage. If you move the Stage by dragging it with the mouse, the TextField does not move since the TextField is not part of the Stage. So what exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe Dialog or Alert is what you really need?

@Abra The screenshots are a little unclear due to the IDE being in the background, but in the first screenshot, there is a popup in the red circle. That popup is the "input method candidate box". But the OP is saying it's in the wrong position—it should be closer to the TextField, like in the second screenshot. In the first screenshot, the TextField is in a Popup; in the second screenshot, it's directly in a Stage.

@Slaw Is the "input method candidate box" part of JavaFX? When I ran the sample code in the question, it did not appear. How do I get it to appear?

@XiaoJiawei I see you posted a similar question which you deleted.

@Abra That part I'm not quite sure about. I don't have any experience using Windows with any language other than English. Some cursory research brought me to input method editors. They enable "a user to input text in a language that can't be represented easily on a standard QWERTY keyboard". It seems these editors are "built into the system". But I don't know what API is being used to interact with them, or if JavaFX is using that API incorrectly when a text input is in a Popup.

Though again, I don't have experience with these input method editors. I'm not even sure what the OP is experiencing is truly a bug.

@Abra You need to open Windows Settings, go to Language & Region, add the language Chinese, and then add Microsoft Pinyin.

@Abra The candidate box is provided by the input method. JavaFX should provide the correct position to the input method so that the candidate box can move to the correct position. However, in the first example, it shows that JavaFX did not provide the correct position. When using other software, such as Chrome, the candidate box always follows the input cursor.

@Slaw I am certain this is a JavaFX bug, because in other software, such as Chrome, the candidate box can follow the input cursor.

@Slaw bug1, bug2

I have submitted a bug, follow-up process JDK-8336423
